# How to find how much data in the transmit buffer?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

How do you find how many bytes are currently waiting in the transmit buffer?

I'm trying to diagnose a weird serial disconnection problem with an Arduino Uno and a rosserial node. It works fine for 10-20 minutes, and then mysteriously losing connection. At first, I thought the Arduino was running out of memory, but I'm able to use the MemoryFree library to log available memory, and it never drops below 9051 bytes.

I now want to make sure the problem isn't because the serial buffer is overflowing, from the Arduino trying to send too much data.

Comment: tx buffer doesn't overflow. the write function of HardwareSerial waits for space in the tx buffer

Comment: You mean the: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/availableforwrite/ As @Juraj wrote, the tx buffer does not overflow, if you send too much data the Arduino is slowed down a lot (100 times or more) because it is waiting for space in the tx buffer.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to know (not that it would do you any good) you can use the `Serial.availableForWrite()` function (which returns how much space is left in the buffer) and subtract the returned value from the size of the buffer.

```
int used = 64 - Serial.availableForWrite(); // Assuming a 64 byte buffer
```

I haven't tested it, but you may be able to use `SERIAL_TX_BUFFER_SIZE` instead of the `64` to make it properly portable.

```
int used = SERIAL_TX_BUFFER_SIZE - Serial.availableForWrite(); // Possibly portable
```

Answer (score 0):

> I now want to make sure the problem isn't because the serial buffer is
>   overflowing, from the Arduino trying to send too much data.

If you are using the software serial Arduino library there is a way to [check for overflow](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialOverflow).

Comment: that is for rx buffer